# C++ cast operator of pointer

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, conversion-operator

I tried the following code sample but A* aa = c; does not compile. Why is the conversion operator not called? The same example without pointers works. So I do not know why C must inherit from A? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I know coding something like this makes no sense. But I just want to understand the conversion stuff.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {    
public:
  int mValue = 0;
};

class B : public A{
public:
  operator A*() { 
    return this;
  }
};

class C {
public:
  operator A*() {
    return new A();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  B* b = new B();
  A* a = b;

  C* c = new C();
  A* aa = c;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because expression `c` has type `C*`, not `C`, which is required for the conversion operator to be called. `C*` and `A*` are unrelated types and no conversion exists between them.

```
A* aa = *c;
```

would work.

`A* a = b;` works because conversion from a pointer to derived class to a pointer to base class is legal and implicit (it doesn't call the conversion operator, mind you).

Answer (score 1):

The conversion operator is not called, **because there is no fitting one**.

Actually, there *cannot be* a fitting one, as you are trying to assign from a pointer to one type to a pointer to a different, non-base type.

You can only override operators if you have at least one user-defined type, but the argument is a pointer, and thus not a user-defined-type, and the result (the conversion-operator is the only one where the result is matched) is not either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
A *aa = *c;
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
A *aa = c->operator A*();
```

On the other hand `A* a = b;` is an example of [upcasting](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php) which happens implicitly in C++ and many other languages.

Note that you have defined operator for class B and class C and not for pointers to these classes.

[Check live demo here](http://ideone.com/ETpjIC)

**Learnings:** There is no implicit conversion to pointers of unrelated types.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer can only ever point to objects of its own class, or to objects of a derived type. Since C does not inherit from A, your code will not work.

I would strongly recommend you have a look at "C++ in 21 days" (search online), the pointer and references section.